# Density of the set of numbers of the form $x^2+2y^2$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a natural number $k$ such that for all intervals (of positive numbers) of length $k$, there is at least one element of the form $x^2+2y^2,$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers?

Answer (score 4):

Let $p$ be a prime congruent to $5$ or $7$ modulo $8$. Then $p$
can only divide $x^2+2y^2$ if $p\mid x$ and $p\mid y$, so that then
$p^2\mid(x^2+2y^2)$. Therefore if $m\equiv p\pmod{p^2}$ then
$m$ cannot be of the form $x^2+2y^2$.

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be $k$ distinct primes of this form
(there are infinitely many by Dirichlet). By the Chinese remainder theorem
there is some $z\in\Bbb N$ with $z\equiv p_j-j\pmod{p_j^2}$
for all $j$. Then $z+j$ cannot be an $x^2+ny^2$. Then none
of $z+1,\ldots,z+k$ is an $x^2+ny^2$.

Comment: Just for the record, since Dirichlet's theorem is rather advanced: One can elementarily show that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 5,7 \pmod{8}$. If $p_1,\dotsc,p_k$ are odd primes, then $(p_1\cdot \dotsc \cdot p_k)^2 + 4$ has a prime factor $\equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, and that is different from the $p_{\kappa}$. And for $p \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$ one considers $(p_1\cdot \dotsc \cdot p_k)^2 - 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer One can be even more elementary: consider the prime factorisation of $8p_1\cdots p_k-1$. It has a prime factor $q\equiv 5$ or $7\pmod 8$ distinct from the $p_j$.

Comment: Good point. $5$ _or_ $7$ is enough for the purpose at hand.